# Почему не выполняется скрипт локально на OpenServer?

Tags: javascript

```html
<a href='javascript:;'>copypatse</a>
<script>
  document.querySelector('a').onclick = function(e) {
    if (document.selection) {
      const range = document.body.createTextRange();
      range.moveToElementText(this);
      range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
      const range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNode(this);
      window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
    document.execCommand('copy');
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: поместите скрипт ниже html

Comment: хм.. вчера даже при выполнении здесь на сайте писалась ошибка.. к сожалению не помню какая.. сейчас же всё работает..

Comment: Пользуясь случаем:
Как сделать несколько ссылок на одной странице с разными названиями?
Что бы при нажатии на любую из них копировался текст той на которую произведено нажатие